# Java Array of Objects Crashes During Initialization

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of objects - so essentially an array of object references.  Inside the class that I am referencing, there is another reference.  I need to initialize this data structure but during init, it crashes.  I am trying to initialize the reference inside the referenced class but it always remains null, so there is some Java "thing" that I don't understand yet.  This seems so simple yet so frustrating.  Here's a dumbed-down example of the problem:

```
public class ref1
{
    public int myInt;
}
public class ref2
{
    public ref1 myRef;
}
public ref2 buffer[];
int i;

// Code to initialize the above data structures:
buffer = new ref2[255];
for (i=0; i<255; i++)
{
    buffer[i] = new ref2();
    buffer[i].myRef = new ref1();   // (1) ALWAYS returns null????
}
```

Eventually the code above will crash with a "ArrayOutOfBoundsException" at the line where I have the (1) marker.  The second thing I notice in the debugger is that myRef is always set to null.  Why is it that I cannot create and reference a ref1 object?????

If I comment out the line marked with (1), there's no exception trap, so the problem is there.

Thanks for anyone who can explain this to a total noob...

Comment: It would be a lot easier to figure out what's going on if you show your code as a compilable example that reproduces the error.  What you've posted runs fine for me after fixing syntax errors

Comment: If you do as @Affe suggests, you'll likely isolate the error and be able to recognize and fix it without our help.

Comment: It seems likely that you have a mismatch between the bound of the for loop at the number of elements allocated for `buffer`. Otherwise, there's no reason for an out of bounds exception. As well, my guess would be that `.myRef` appears as null when debugging because you've broken on the line with the assignment, which means it hasn't yet taken place. `new` will always return a non-null object.

Comment: Wel, OK I am a java noob but not a total noob.  ;)  I checked the array bounds and I have stepped over the line in question.  All elements in the array have null values for myRef.  The actual code is posted in an answer below.

Comment: Wait for Jon Skeet to answer this.

Comment: I'm betting that Jon Skeet won't tell him that it's a compiler bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
salam package cruft;

/**
 * BadRef description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link
 * @since 6/25/12 5:53 PM
 */
public class BadRef {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ref2 buffer[] =  new ref2[255];
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; ++i) {
            buffer[i] = new ref2();
```

Comment: I'd definitely encourage you to add some context/explanation surrounding this (rather than having a code-only answer) as that makes the answer more useful.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.  I have no idea what you're doing:

```
package cruft;

/**
 * BadRef description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link
 * @since 6/25/12 5:53 PM
 */
public class BadRef {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ref2 buffer[] =  new ref2[255];
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; ++i) {
            buffer[i] = new ref2();
            buffer[i].myRef = new ref1();
            buffer[i].myRef.myInt = i;
            System.out.println(buffer[i]);
        }
    }
}


class ref1 {
    public int myInt;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("ref1");
        sb.append("{myInt=").append(myInt);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

class ref2 {
    public ref1 myRef;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("ref2");
        sb.append("{myRef=").append(myRef);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're inspecting the value of buffer[i].myRef at each iteration, it will really be null every time. This is correct, because at each iteration, the buffer[i] is a new ref2 instance, with a null myRef field. The ref2 instances are stored in the previous positions of the array.

So, in the debugger, if you expand the buffer[] array values you're going to see the previously constructed objects in the positions below the current one.

As for the ArrayOutOfBoundsException... I'm assuming you're actually referring to the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (please correct me if this is not the case). In this case, the boundaries are correctly set. You're creating a 255-positions array and you're correctly iterating it from 0 to 254 (the **i < 255** part). So, this works fine. Please double-check the code.